# How to make a new SAPI voice for text-to-speech?

Tags: text-to-speech, voice-recognition, sapi

Anyone know how to create own SAPI TTS voices? Are there any docs / apis / algorithms? I have not the slightest idea where I could begin. I want to use the voice in my own software and also I want to be able to sell it so it can be used in other 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a component that implement TTSEngine API, see the documentation for details:

[TTS Engine Vendor Porting Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For a practical example of the engine implementation you can download sample engine as well as you can check [Espeak SAPI implementation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/).